# Read csv file in PHP with text in Hebrew

Tags: php, csv

I want to import a CSV file I created in PHP and contains text in Hebrew.

This is how I created the file :

```
header("Content-Type: application/comma-separated-values; charset=UTF-16LE");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");

res = "";
foreach($data as $row) {
     foreach($row as $coll) {
          $res .= $coll . "\t";
     }

     $res .= "\r\n";
}

// Convert $res from UTF8 to UTF-16LE and add special chars at the beginning
echo chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($res, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

That code works and I get a CSV file with the Hebrew characters displayed correctly.

When I'm trying to read the same file, the Hebrew characters are not displaying well (ÔÒàÔ âÜ ÔÒÕã 0 for example). This is the code I've tried :

```
$fp = fopen($file_full_path,'r') or die("can't open file");
print "<table>\n";
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
     print '<tr>';
     for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) 
     {
         $val = $csv_line[$i];
         print '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
     }
     print "</tr>\n";
}

print '</table>\n';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
```

This solution should work for English, Hebrew, French, German characters and more.

Answer (score 1):

basically you need to use the following to convert the string to utf-8

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($data[$c], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $data[$c])
```

here is the full function for reading utf-8 csv file

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("mycsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data =  fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($data[$c], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $data[$c]) . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the browser what character set to expect. Add this line to the top of your PHP script which is displaying the data:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16LE");
```

If you want the document to pass W3C validation, you will also need to declare this in a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` of the document.

You may also need to handle the BOM you placed in the file on the first row, I'd suggest calling `fseek($fp, 2);` before the loop if you know it will always be there.

Also you should use the [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to generate the CSV file in the first place.

Comment: When adding header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16LE"); to the top of the script, the output looks like this : 搯浯楡獮振摯汩慹 ...
I've tried using fputcsv() to generate the CSV file, but the Hebrew characters didn't displayed well when opening it with Excel

Comment: @Shani1351 OK, that's odd - are you sure the content is little endian? Try `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16BE`

Comment: When using Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16BE the output looks like this : "Aging process êהליךԠÔזדקנותԉ"...

Comment: @Shani1351 Err... right. Can you post the CSV file somewhere? E.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Shani1351 OK `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` is *I think* working for me, although I'm not 100% sure because I don't speak hebrew.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work... This is the output I get for a row with Hebrew : 5 Body Protection Body Protection ���� �� ���� 0

Comment: What if you load the file directly in your browser? Are you sure the font you are using is capable of displaying those characters?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've decided to use PHPExcel for both export and import and it works great with utf-8

Comment: @Shani1351 Cool, glad you found an acceptable solution. Maybe you could post that as an answer here and accept you own answer, to help future visitors?